# How to implement firebase authentication in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am unable to use firebase authentication in my app.My android version of appcomat does not support this version of firebase

I have reduced the app version from 28.0.0 to 27.0.0

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Hello Aditya, Welcome to stack overflow.  Do you happen to have any additional details you could offer in your question that may be helpful in locating the answer?

Comment: it show issue id:GradleCompatible

Comment: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less...
Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

Comment: Hello Aditya I faces this many times .It occurs only due to dependencies and gradle versions mixing....Please check your classpath verion,and according and others versions according to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this problem --

1) Add a line in build.gradle(app) depedencies:-

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

[Look at the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceLJe.jpg)

2) update in the build.gradle(project) dependencies:-
update classpath of google service from 4.1.0 to 4.2.0
[update google service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJcXm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try to use the latest SDK for auth and core, 
`com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0`

[Firebase release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions)